# Can you stop the cops appearing in payday 2

Tags: payday-2

Is it possible to set off an ecm jammer and kill all the guards and cuff all the civilians so the alarm is never set off in a bank heist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, altough it takes a bit more than that.

It's called "going quiet" (as opposed to "going loud" where you either prepare to fail or don't even try) and every mission where this is possible is marked by the little blue ghost icon. Also, the mission description often mentions that "stealth is an option".

[image: Example of the "little blue ghost"]

For this to work on a bank job you'd need to make sure no alarms are raised (by either the tellers or the guard monitoring the security cameras), take out or subdue all the guards, keep all the civilians down (cuffing is optional, but makes your life easier) and make sure nobody at the street notices anything weird (or if they do, they join the other hostages).

Also, it's sometime possible to do it by only taking out a couple of guards and civilians. You just need a quiet drill and a lot of sneaking.

Comment: Thank you, if you have xbox live you can show me sometime ig

Comment: @Sparta270 Remember to mark the answer accepted if you found it solved your question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes but only on some heists, possibly only on lower difficulties for some Heists.

On the heist called "bank heist" you can. You might need players with extra zip cuff skills but I have done it, often without even an ecm jammer.

On most Heists most of the guards have pagers. The pager goes off when the guard is killed or taken hostage. If a pager is left alone the cops are called. You can answer pagers, but only 4 times. Therefore if there are at least 5 pagers in a Heist, you can't alert the map and avoid cops.

Comment: I think it's entirely possible in higher difficulties. Just harder.

Comment: The question specifically said "Shoot all the guards" It wasn't just about finishing on stealth. If there are 5 or more pagers it is simply impossible to shoot all the guards and not have cops show up.

Comment: That was propably inexperienced player thinking that that's what you'd _need to do_ to stealth a mission. I think they're more conserned about stealthing the mission (by any means) than murdering innocent guards just doing their job. But the point about the number of available pager responses is a good point to make.